# How to handle pagination in selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is my code when I run it goes to the 2nd page and stop it not looping all pages and search the required element. It should look for particular text in a page and click on the link of it.

```
    if (driver.getTitle().contains("Article properties")) {
        WebElement assigninitial = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Assign reviewer for initial review"));
        assigninitial.click();
    } else {
        //pagination code
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app/main/app-mytasks/div[1]/section/div/pagination/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<WebElement> pagination = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/app/main/app-mytasks/div[1]/section/div/pagination/ul/li[5]/a"));
        // checkif pagination link exists 

        if ((pagination).size() > 0) {
            //System.out.print("pagination exists"); 

            // click on pagination link 

            for (int i = 0; i < pagination.size(); i++) {
                pagination.get(i).click();
                if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Article properties")) {
                    WebElement assigninitial = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Assign reviewer for initial review"));
                    assigninitial.click();
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("pagination not exists");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should search for `pagination` on every page. Because when you click on the pagination link the page changes and all `paginagtion` elements become stale.

Comment: You are using  findElements and have passed By.xpath...I believe xpath are used to identify a single element and hence call to findElements will always return a single element.As a result of this, your loop will run only once...Verify this by asserting for pagination.Size..Are you getting more then 1 element? I would suggest using find by css-selector to get all the pagination link elements...Please share the fragment of html for pagination so that we can help you  write an appropriate css-selector for it.

Comment: @Nish26 XPaths can be used to locate multiple elements just as CSS selectors do.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void pagination_check() throws InterruptedException {
    loader_wait(5);    //wait until 'loader'  loading
    List<WebElement> pagination = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//page-navigation/div/div/span/a")); 
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    if (pagination.size() > 0) { 
        System.out.println("pagination exists and size=>"+pagination.size()); 
        int page_no=pagination.size();
        for (int i = 2; i <= pagination.size(); i++) {      
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//page-navigation/div/div/span")));    //for 
 scroller move
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//page-navigation/div/div/span/a["+i+"]")));
            loader_wait(5);      //wait 
        } 
    } else { 
        System.out.println("no pagination");
    } 
}
```